# Ratio of Electrons with spin up to spin down in say, the human body?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin

What would be the approximate ratio of electrons with spin up to those those spin down in the human body? I might guess it would be around 1:1, any suggestions?

Comment: Zero over zero is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is meaningless. You could, if you wanted to, count up all the ions in the human body, assign each of them their electron quantum numbers as you learned in intro Chemistry, count them all up, divide, and obtain an answer to your question. The answer, however, would be physically meaningless, a pointless mathematical contrivance based on a misunderstanding.

Until it's involved in a particular interaction, an electron's direction of spin is a weighted superposition of all possible directions. The probability distribution is the electron and the electron is the probability distribution. There is no such thing as a collection of predetermined quantum numbers waiting to be discovered, only an interaction that temporarily collapses the probability distribution to a set of eigenvalues.

When electrons are associated with atoms, for any particular interaction they will line up the way you learned in Intro Chemistry. So, in that regard, we can talk about the spin of an atom - that's the sum of the spin configurations that it will be found in in any given interaction, relative to an arbitrary "up" direction that is particular to that specific interaction. This is very powerful for predicting how atoms will interact (form chemical bonds, etc), but it can't be taken any farther. It's only meaningful to discuss the quantum numbers of a quantum with relation to a single interaction. A macroscopic object is a continuous process of countless interactions, and as such can't be meaningfully described in terms of quantum numbers, even in averages and approximations.